# Replicating "Formula Drag" Google Spreadsheet functionality with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-apps-script-editor

Some background to my problem:

A common way to quickly calculate results in spreadsheet applications like Google Sheets is to write a formula in a cell, and then `"drag"` that formula to be applied to other cells.

If cells that are referenced in the formula are not locked, the formula is updated to reflect the same relationship between the cell in which the formula exists, and the cell which the formula references.

I am writing a program which needs to update the formulas of many cells; each formula unique to each cell because of the `"unlocked"` cell references I mentioned earlier. In order to do this, I've come up with the following solution:

Have formulas which I would like to place in my sheet exist in a different sheet, and call `(range).getFormulas()` to get the desired formulas, and then apply to my sheet with `(range).setFormulas()`.

This will work fine, it's just that I don't want to have to reference a permanently existing sheet to access the appropriate formulas.

Is there a way to replicate this `"formula drag"` functionality that preserves cell references within the code completely so that copying formulas as plain text isn't necessary?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Search ``Autofill`` in the documentation.

Comment: See also [Range.copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range)).  This will copy formulas and adjust references just like copy and paste.